# org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableNotFoundException while creating Hive table on Hbase data

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hbase, managed

i am trying to creating hive managed table based on the hbase table.

i created sample hbase table like :

```
create ‘hbase_table’,’name’
```

and copied **hbase-site.xml** to hive/conf,

and created **auxlib** directory in hive root directory, added zookeeper, hbase-hive-handler, hbase jars to **auxlib** and given that path to **hive.aux.jars.path** in **hive-site.xml**

loaded the data into hbase table, i can able to access the hbase data.

now i am trying to create hive external table. here is my syntax:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hive_table (Row_key string, First_name string,last_name string,age int,City string,Team string) STORED BY ‘org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler’ WITH SERDEPROPERTIES(“hbase.columns.mapping”=”:key,name:first_name ,name:last_name,details:age,details:city,details:team”) TBLPROPERTIES (“hbase.table.name” = “hbase_table”);
```

**i am getting following exception:**

```
java.sql.SQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableNotFoundException: hbase_table
```